# Problem with UpperCase, str object has no attribute 'isUpperCase'

Tags: python, string

I want the program to change the characters of a string object from lower to capital and vice versa.

So that if I input jOHN, it returns John.

Here I leave you the code:

```
nombre=input('Write the wrong name here: ')

nuevonombre=''
contador=0
while contador <= len(nombre):
    if nombre[contador].isUpperCase == true:
        nombre[contador].lower()
    else:
        nombre[contador].upper()
    nuevonombre = nuevonombre + nombre[contador]
    contador+=1
print(nuevonombre)
```

But when I run the program, the terminal gives the following error:

```
if nombre[contador].isUpperCase == true:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isUpperCase'
```

Maybe I shouldn't use .isUpperCase, if that's not it what should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: try isupper(). https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `isupper()` method.

```py
if nombre[contador].isupper():
```

Comment: I've changed it and still gives the same error:                                                                          if nombre[contador].isupper() IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @cristianoronaldo that is not the same error as mentioned in original question

Answer (score 1):

There is no function `isUpperCase` in python, it is called `'john'.isupper()`.

Your problem can be solved much simpler using pythons slicing syntax and simple string functions:

```py
def fix_str(s: str) -> str:
    return s[0].upper() + s[0:].lower()

>>> fix_str('jOhN')
'John'
```

Comment: The OP wants to change the case to all the characters, not only the first char should be capital.

Answer (score 0):

a bit shorter solution using list comprehension:

```
input_name = input('Write the wrong name here: ')
res = "".join([x.lower() if x.isupper() else x.upper() for x in list(input_name)])
print(res)
```

where `list` converts your input to list of chars, and `join` converts it back to string.